# How can I add CSS style into backend my own joomla template?

Tags: templates, joomla

How can I add CSS style into backend of my own template in Joomla? I'm trying to develop my own template for Joomla. Is there a solution to add CSS style to backend of template?

Regards Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a new template for backend too
If you are experienced web designer you can use the Admin Custom CSS (thekrotek.com) plugin – which allows you to redesign the Joomla back-end and build an individual and unique style with your custom CSS. Remember to enable the plugin and create a custom.css file in the administrator/templates/your_template/css/ folder.

Comment: But how can I add this .css file into backend for my custom template?

Comment: you can include it in your template index.php file: \administrator\templates\your_template\index.php

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following solution that works, even though it is certainly not technically the prettiest.

Add to templateDetails.xml:

```
<field 
  name="EigenesCSS" 
  type="textarea" 
  default="" 
  label="Eigens CSS" 
  description="Fügen Sie hier Ihr persönlicher CSS Code ein." 
  rows="10" 
  cols="5" 
  filter="raw"
 />
```

After that, add the following code in the head area of the index.php file after the regular links to the CSS files ($doc->addStyleSheet):

```
if (!empty($this->params->get('EigenesCSS'))) {
    echo '<style>' . $this->params->get('EigenesCSS') . '</style>';
}
```

It is important that the code is loaded after the other CSS files, because this is the only way to overwrite the standard CSS definitions.